# printf address arithmethic of two pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
int strlen(char *s)
{ 
    char *p = s; 
    while (*p != '\0') 
        p++; 
    return (p - s); 
}
```

`p-s` gives the number of characters advanced over, that is, the string length

when I printf("%d") p or s I get big numbers (that are different each time I recompile program)

are these numbers correlated with the address of the pointers? A printf %d with p or s alone is a random high number but `p-s` isn't

Comment: You should post a complete program. `printf("%d")` does not make sense, it misses a parameter. `printf("%d\n", strlen("This is a test string"));` works like expected: https://ideone.com/BCtUtc

Answer (score 4):

When you print pointers like `p` and `s`, use the `%p` format specifier. For technical correctness, also convert them to `void *`:

```
printf("p is %p.\n", (void *) p);
printf("s is %p.\n", (void *) s);
```

If you print with a mismatching format specifier, the behavior is undefined.

When you print the values of these pointers, you will generally see the addresses where the string passed to your function starts (`s`) and ends (`p`). (The C implementation is required to print something that represents the pointer. It is not required to be the address as a simple number, but common C implementations print the address in hexadecimal.) Those may be big values because the operating system, including the program loader, assigns various places in the memory address space for your program to use.

Those addresses may vary because the loader deliberately uses random addresses to foil any attackers that try to make use of known addresses to break programs. (There are other reasons the addresses may vary too.)

`p-s` is constant because you are passing the same string each time, so the distance between where it starts and where it ends is always the same.

Comment: Good part about "not required to be the address as a simple number,".

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on why to use `const` here `(const void *)`?

Comment: @alk: I have edited it; standard C requires using `void *`.

Answer (score 2):

`p-s` is the difference between them. The difference between two number is basically the offset.
From `§6.5.6`

> The result of the binary - operator is the difference resulting from
>   the subtraction of the second operand from the first.

That's what you get when you do `p-s`.

But `p` and `s` contains address which should be printed using `%p` format specifier.

From standard `§6.5.6.8` (The reason why `&p-&s` is not possible)

> . If **both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the
>   same array object, or one past the last element of the array object**,
>   the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, **the behavior
>   is undefined**

#### Different every time...

Also you said that those are difference each time those `p` and `s` contained value because the memory assigned to the program may vary time to time. That's why the address changes.

But the difference will always be same because they are at the difference of `length` of the string.

#### Random high Number:

That is because the lower address are *generally* reserved for system level programs. The user space programs dont get chun allocated from there. That's why those are quite big.

Also from 6.5.6

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object, or one past the last element of the array object;
>   the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
>   elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its
>   type (a signed integer type) is ptrdiff_t defined in the 
>   header.

For using `ptrdiff_t` the `printf` format specifier will be `%td`.

Comment: @anthonyMichaels.: Yes the pointer arithmetic would work only if they belong to the same array or one past the array element.Here that doesn;t hold in case of `&p-&q`

Answer (score 2):

Let's see a bit details about pointer subtraction. Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.6

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined,
>   and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` header. [....]

So, bottom line

- you must use `%td` to print the result of `p - s`, type `ptrdiff_t`.
- for `p` and `s`, you mist use `%p` conversion specifier, as both of them are pointer type.

Any variation from above, and you'll cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: OP's function returns `int`, so `"%d"` is the correct specifier to print the return value of the function.

Comment: @mch the problem is in the function signature itself, I guess once OP is aware of the type of the result, that comes as a natural next step to correct the function signature and thus the FS, don't you think?

Comment: `size_t my_strlen(...  return (size_t) (p - s); }` would make even more sense.